# MS-SQL single_user mode query interrupted

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run the following query

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db
    SET SINGLE_USER
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (my_db, 2);

ALTER DATABASE my_db
    SET MULTI_USER;
```

The query starts executing, the database goes to single usermode, I see my cpu and disk usage spike for a few seconds (between 5 and 20s) and then I get the error.

```
Database 'my_db' is already open and can only have one user at a time.
```

I've had some other issues while trying to run the shrink in multi user mode. How can I get exclusive access to the database while the shrink is running?

Comment: Are you actually connected to `my_db2`? If not, use a `USE` statement to take the only available connection. If you are, sounds like someone is changing it back to multi user.

Comment: Why are you putting this into single user mode? DBCC SHRINKDATABASE shouldn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to avoid the only connection being used by someone else:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE my_db
    SET SINGLE_USER
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

USE my_db;     -- Grab that single connection immediately after db is in single_user mode
GO
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (my_db, 2);
GO

ALTER DATABASE my_db
    SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Comment: Update: that didn't work, sadly, still getting the same error

Comment: Check if the sql agent is running? If its running then Stop and run the above query.

Comment: Agent won't be able to steal that connection @RedDevil . If the OP is still getting the behaviour, then this means someone/something is changing it back to `MULTI_USER`.

Comment: Does SET SINGLE_USER have to be run from master? Can't you run it from the database you want to set and use ALTER DATABASE CURRENT?

Comment: @Larnu it stays on single user after the query fails. I also should be the only one accessing it since it's running in a docker container locally.

Comment: Try removing the `USE my_db;` (and the following `GO`)  in the above, @Gelunox. Does that work? Perhaps `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` is trying to create an additional connection, which is can't due to you already using it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is.
Run:

```
exec sp_who
```

This will return you the process and their SP ID which is connected to your DB.

Then run the kill command

```
KILL SPID
```